# Graphene Unit test returning object location

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, graphene-python

In a unit test where I'm trying to ensure that my boolean field method returns the correct value, I'm getting the object location instead of the actual value. Am I on the right path?

Graphene Helper:

```
def boolean_field(field):
    return graphene.Boolean(resolver=lambda self, *_: GrapheneHelper.get_json_field(self, field))
```

Graphene test:

```
def test_boolean_field(self):
    """ Return graphene boolean field """
    self.assertEqual(GrapheneHelper.boolean_field('has_title'), True)
```

This is the error I get: `AssertionError: <graphene.types.scalars.Boolean object at 0x11369b210> != True`

Comment: Try changing `assertEqual` to `assertTrue`.  `assertEqual(x, y)` tests if x == y.  `assertTrue(x)` tests if bool(x) is True.  And you're not "getting the address" of anything - the text you see is the default Python formatting for a type that doesn't define `__str__` or `__repr__`.  Apparently that's the case for `graphene.types.scalars.Boolean`.

Comment: Thank you Paul! I did need to do that. That however is only part of my problem... What I think I need to do is mock the resolver so that I get the actual value and not just the object location. I will post back when I find a solution :)

Comment: Honestly, I seriously doubt that the object location is playing any role here except in the print statement.  In python the ONLY way to see the object location (as far as I know) is with the built-in function id().  It's incredibly rare that it would be of any interest - I've only ever used it for some weird diagnostic purposes.  In fifteen years of Python programming I have *never* used id() in production code.

Comment: Got it - thank you for clarifying that. I had never seen a python default like ```graphene.types.scalars.Boolean``` - I didn't know what else to call it

Comment: Yeah, most standard classes define both `__str__` and `__repr__`, so when you print one of those objects it looks somewhat human.  It's nice to provide those functions when you design a class of your own, but of course that takes time and effort :-)

Comment: I solved my problem using python's isinstance builtin method:    

    ```def test_boolean_field(self):
        """ Return graphene boolean field """
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(GrapheneHelper.boolean_field('has_title'), graphene.types.scalars.Boolean), True)```

Comment: I hope you realize that you are testing the *type* of the object in the field named "has_title", not its *truth value*.  For instance `a=False; isinstance(a, bool)` returns `True` because `a` is of type `bool`.  But `a` itself is False.